# LM386 LTspice simulation output problem

Tags: operational-amplifier, amplifier, ltspice, lm386

[image]

[image]

[Source](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm386.pdf)

I am trying to simulate this circuit before setting it up on breadboard.
I have downloaded [this](https://ecee.colorado.edu/%7Emathys/ecen1400/Software/LM386.cir) model for simulation, and set up the circuit.

[image]

Transient simulation for vout:

[image]

What am I missing here? I was expecting an amplified sinus wave. Is this because there is no load at the end of capacitor? If so how should I simulate it properly to see it before actually setting up the circuit?

Comment: Try reducing the sinewave amplitude to 0.05.

Comment: Are you feeding 5V sine in? That's like over 10 times over the limit.

Comment: You are right! Sorry there happened a typo I guess. I changed it and It works now thank you.

Comment: You are missing the load. Place like 8 ohms as load.

Comment: You could simulate the speaker by adding an 8 ohm resistor between the 250uf capacitor and ground.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Input voltage range is too high. Limit is +/- 0.4V.